# Shortest time to cover certain distance (Jerk involved)

Tags: calculus, kinematics

I faced a kinematics problem in certain physics book today but I thought of asking my doubt here as it is more of a mathematical problem.

"A fun drive in an amusement park runs between two spots that are $2 km$ apart.For safety reasons the acceleration of drive is limited to $+4m/s^2$ or $-4m/s^2$.The maximum permissible magnitude of jerk can be $+1m/s^3$ or $-1m/s^3$.The drive has a maximum speed of $144 km/h$.Find the shortest  time taken by the drive to travel between the spots.

I tried to assume the function of displacement as a cubic function of the form $x=t^3+at^2+bt+c $ since jerk (rate change of acceleration ) is possible.But I haven't been able to reach the result still.Can someone guide me please.THANKS.

Comment: Sounds more like a periodic function will do better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you need to compose a piecewise continuous function. If we integrate for constant jerk,
$$s=s_0+v_0t+\frac12a_0t^2+\frac16jt^3$$
Where $s_0$, $v_0$, and $a_0$ are the initial displacement, velocity, and acceleration, and $j$ is the constant jerk. So you want to get going with maximum jerk until you reach maximum acceleration, continue with this acceleration for a little while, then with maximum negative jerk decreases your acceleration until it reached $0$ just when you reach maximum velocity. Then cruise along until you get near the end when you have to reverse the process. I am pretty sure that the time to the halfway point should be half the total time.

For the first piece, $j=1$, $a=a_0+jt=t=a_{\max}=4$ when $t=4$ seconds. Then $v=v_0+a_0t+\frac12jt^2=0+0+\frac12\cdot4^2=8$ meters per second, and $s=\frac{32}3$ meters.

For the third piece, recall that maximum velocity is $40$ meters per second $v=40=v_0+a_0t+\frac12jt^2=v_0+4\cdot4-\frac12\cdot4^2=v_0+8$ because it takes $4$ seconds to slow down from maximum acceleration to zero at maximum jerk. Thus we have for the second piece $v=32=v_0+a_0t+\frac12jt^2=8+4t+0$ so the second piece lasts for $6$ seconds. The second piece advances $s$ by $s-s_0=v_0t+\frac12a_0t^2+\frac16jt^3=8\cdot6+\frac12\cdot4\cdot6^2+0=120$ meters, and the third piece advances $s$ by $s-s_0=v_0t+\frac12a_0t^2+\frac16jt^3=32\cdot4+\frac12\cdot4\cdot4^2-\frac16\cdot4^3=\frac{448}3$ meters, so at $t=4+6+4=14$ seconds, we are at $s=\frac{32}3+120+\frac{448}3=280$ meters and cruising at maximum velocity of $40$ meters per second.

It takes another $\frac{1000-280}{40}=18$ seconds to reach the halfway point, so we should complete our journey in $2(14+18)=64$ seconds total.

**EDIT**: Here is a table of displacement, velocity, and acceleration at the time points when the jerk is changed and the jerk before and after the change.
$$\begin{array}{cccccc}
t&s&v&a&j_{before}&j_{after}\\
0&0&0&0&0&1\\
4&\frac{32}3&8&4&1&0\\
10&\frac{392}3&32&4&0&-1\\
14&280&40&0&-1&0\\
50&1720&40&0&0&-1\\
54&\frac{5608}3&32&-4&-1&0\\
60&\frac{5968}3&8&-4&0&1\\
64&2000&0&0&1&0
\end{array}$$

Comment: What are $j_1$ and $j_2$?

Comment: $j_1$ is the jerk just before the time $t$ in its row and $j_2$ is the jerk just after. Would it be more readable if I changed them to $j(t^-)$ and $j(t^+)$?

Comment: I wrote it explicitly.Thanks btw :)

Comment: Just one more doubt.How to understand when to put $j=0$,and $  j=-1$ ?

Comment: The guiding principle is that you want to get going as fast as you can as soon as you can. So you start with maximum $j=+1$ but you have to stop jerking when you reach maximum $a=+4$. You are going to have to jerk backwards at some point because you can't exceed the maximum $v=+40$. That's why I worked out the third time interval before the second, because I had to determine what time I needed to set $j=-1$ so that I would reach $a=0$ at the same time I reached $v=+40$.

Comment: Alright.Upto that I understand now.But after that how did you know 18 seconds is needed to reach halfway ? And how did you know total time will be exactly double ?

Comment: Well, $\frac{1000m-280m}{40m/s}=18s$ so that's what it takes to get to the halfway point. I was using the symmetry of the problem and just guessing that you could reverse the procedure that got you up to speed fastest and slow you down as soon as possible as well. That's one reason I wrote up the table because following through the table line by line you can show that the assumption really is valid.

Comment: Excellent answer. I understood it all now :)